# Queue not holding the updated data

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have a simple multi threaded program where one thread is filling the queue, while the other is consuming the queue, I know this example program is buggy, which is closely trying to replicate my application. I don't have an explanation as to why it's behaving this way, I expect the output to be popping 1 , 2 , etc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public :
    int y;
    A(int z):y(z){
        cout << "constructed =" << y << std::endl;
    }
    
    ~A(){
        cout << "destructed =" << y << std::endl;
    }

};
std::mutex lk;

std::queue<shared_ptr<A>> p;
std::condition_variable cv;
int ct = 1;
void waitfordata(){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(lk);
    cv.wait(lock, []{return p.size();});
    cout << "popping  = " << p.front()->y << endl;
    p.pop();
}

void threadhandler(){
    while(1){
        waitfordata();
    }
}
int main()
{

    std::thread foo(threadhandler);
    
    std::shared_ptr<A> svc_resp = std::make_shared<A>(ct++);
    while(1){
        
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(lk);
            p.push(svc_resp);
        }
        cv.notify_one();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::shared_ptr<A> svc_resp = std::make_shared<A>(ct++);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
Ouput which I got
constructed =1
popping  = 1
constructed =2
destructed =2
popping  = 1
constructed =3
destructed =3
popping  = 1
constructed =4
destructed =4
popping  = 1
```

```
Ouput which I  was expecting

constructed =1
destructed =1  <===== why is 1 not destructed
popping  = 1
constructed =2
destructed =2
popping  = 2  <===== why is this not taking the next data 
constructed =3
destructed =3
popping  = 3  <===== why is this not taking the next data 
constructed =4
destructed =4
popping  = 4 <===== why is this not taking the next data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *two* variables named `svc_resp` in `main`. The second one (at the bottom of the `while` loop) will create and briefly own a `shared_ptr<A>` before it is immediately destroyed. This accounts for the constructed and destructed outputs with the increasing numbers.

The first `svc_resp` variable, declared before the `while` loop, as a `y` of `1` and is re-pushed to your queue every loop.

The fix is simple: remove the type name from the second `svc_resp` declaration, turning it into an assignment.

```
svc_resp = std::make_shared<A>(ct++);
```